Turbo Frame not updated
store/index.html.erb
<%= render 'notice' %>
<h1>Products Catalog</h1>
<%= turbo_stream_from 'products' %>

<% if session[:counter] >= 5 %>
    <p class="my-4">You have visited this page <%= pluralize(session[:counter], 'time') %> since last product was added
        to cart</p>
<% end %>

<ul>
    <%= cache @products do %>
        <% @products.each do |product| %>
            <%= cache product do %>
                <%= render partial: 'product', object: product %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</ul>

store/_product.html.erb
<%= turbo_frame_tag(dom_id(product)) do %>
  <li class="mb-6 flex flex-row">
   <%= image_tag(product.images.first.url, class: "object-center w-48 mr-6") %>
   <div>
    <h2><%= product.name %></h2>
    <p><%= sanitize(product.description) %></p>
    <p><%= product.brand.name %></p>
    <p><%= product.category.name %></p>
    <p><%= product.heel_height %></p>
    <div class="mt-3 flex flex-row items-center">
     <p><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></p>
     <%= button_to 'Add to Cart',
                   line_items_path(product_id: product),
                   form_class: "inline",
                   class: "ml-4 rounded-lg py-1 px-2 bg-green-600 text-white " %>
    </div>
   </div>
  </li>
<% end %>

I generated the products_channel using rails g channel products
channel/products_channel.rb
class ProductsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
      stream_from 'products'
  end

  def unsubscribed
      # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed 
  end
end

When I run the server I got the confirmation that the channel is up
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-07-31 17:57:23 +0700 
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC 
Started GET "/cable" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2024-07-31 17:57:23 +0700 
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Hotwire::Livereload::ReloadChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
Hotwire::Livereload::ReloadChannel is streaming from hotwire-reload

This is my update action in products_controller.rb
def update
  if @product.update(product_params.except(:images))
    if params[:product][:images].present?
      @product.images.destroy_all
      images = params[:product][:images]
      process_images(images)
    end

    @product.broadcast_replace_later_to 'products',
                                            target: dom_id(@product),
                                            partial: 'store/product',
                                            locals: { product: @product }
    redirect_to product_path(@product), notice: 'Product was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

For some reasons, after submitting the update form, the index tab in my browser doesn't get updated and I don't get any related log messages, as well as no javascript error in the browser console.
Edit: It worked after I changed
 @product.broadcast_replace_later_to 'products',
                                            target: dom_id(@product),
                                            partial: 'store/product',
                                            locals: { product: @product }

to
@product.broadcast_replace_later_to 'products',
                                          partial: 'store/product'

Can someone explain? Thanks

i don't see in the logs that you're subscribed to turbo_stream_from 'products' channel. also you don't need ProductsChannel.

@Alex there are this 2 lines
ProductsChannel is streaming from products```
As for the ```ProductsChannel``` I used the ```rails generate``` command and it created the file for me

you don't need that channel, turbo uses its own channel for that, you should see Turbo::StreamsChannel is streaming from products
